# Wireless range extender stops working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-extender

I have a [Linksys WAP300N](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/accesspoints/WAP300N) that is running in wireless range extender mode.
I have a [Thomson TG 798vn](https://www.google.se/search?q=thomson%20tg789vn&lr=lang_entbs=lr:lang_1en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) connected to the phone line using an adsl splitter.

The Thomson has the wireless network turned on. After doing a reset I've just changed the SSID, and the wireless password, the Channel, and the WPA-PSK Encryption Key.

I have set up the WAP300N exactly like in [this guide](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=28122).

Now for a few weeks, everything runs fine. Our PC's, the Xbox 360, the PS3, and our Android Phones all connect without any issues.
After this grace period, devices that connects through the Linksys WAP300N starts to being unable to connect through the internet. However, there is some connectivity. Almost like DNS has stopped working.
However, assigning a fixed DNS (Thomson IP first, 8888 second) didn't do anything on my phone.

I had exactly the same issue before I last reset the devices, and once before that. All in a period of say 3 months or so.

What happens with the wireless range extension and how can I prevent it? Resetting and reconfiguring the network starts getting old.

Comment: What happens if you reboot the Thompson Modem/router and then the Linksys once the Thompson device is up and running? Power issues can cause strange behaviour

Comment: @DaveM It seems to work. What kind of power issues are you considering?

Comment: I have seen a dip in voltage send a router, modem or other device into a strange state. For example, DHCP suddenly stops but other functions work.  Web interface looks OK but device not working as expected.  Often a reboot resolves the issue.  A UPS solves the issue.  Heat can do same thing. Stacking modem and router often yields undesirable results.